# Combining images for facebook share

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

I have a bunch of overlayed images that create a larger image (it's a build your own jacket application). I want the combination of all the images to be used as the og:image for a facebook share.  How can I best combine the images (php, jquery, etc)?  Should I first combine all the images into one image, or is there a facebook workaround?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Imagick installed on your server, you could do something like this in php to layer the images over one another.

```
$background = new Imagick( "background.png" );
$other_image = new Imagick( "layer1.png" );
$background->compositeImage( $other_image, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0 );
```

You would just have to do something to that effect for each one of the layers. If you don't have Imagick installed on the server you could also use the GD Library.